# g++ 4.8.5 compiles c++14 code silently in c++11 mode

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

To my surprise, the following program compiles just fine:

```
int main()
{ 
    int i = 4;
    [j = i]{}();
}

> g++ --std=c++11 ext.cpp
>
```

The problem is that I *want* this to fail: Generalized Lambda Capture is a C++14 feature, and my current project has a requirement for C++11.

Now, Clang compiles this too with a warning, which I can promote to an error using -Werror=c++14-extensions.  However, I can find no similar flag for g++.  I can use -pedantic-errors or -Werror=pedantic, but those come with way, way more baggage.

Have I overlooked some compiler option for this compiler?

Comment: This appears to be changed in 4.9.0: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wlzpCQAKmjizjY1w

Comment: What's wrong with `-pedantic-errors`? The only "baggage" I know of is it forces you to adhere to the standard version you specify, which is what you want isn't it?

Comment: @KazDragon, It looks like this warning is still classified as `-pedantic` despite the switch not being necessary anymore, so `-pedantic-errors` would be the way to make it an error. I doubt there's any way to single out that type of warning.

Comment: @Galik This is a large codebase.  Changing to -pedantic-errors would also require editing many other files, including third-party headers we're using.

As an example, this also would flag as an error ending a namespace with a ; character.  Which some people do, annoyingly.

Comment: @KazDragon This is the reason I think `-pedantic-errors` should be the default for the compiler and we should only have to specify a flag if we want to use non-standard extensions. But here we are... :)